# How to wait for a line to finish?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with "getPixel" and "setPixel" functions. It seems like when getPixel is executed the task of filling the array with bitmap data goes to background and the program doesn't wait for this task to finish before proceeding to next line.I know this because when I instantly set the processed bitmap to an imageView the bitmap is all black, But when I put a delay after "getPixel" (about 200ms), the result is right. But I prefer not to use delay and actually wait for this "getPixel" to finish before continuing. My question is how. Thank you

```
Bmp1.getPixels(pixes, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
.
.
//Some processing on pixes
.
.
Bmp2.setPixels(pixes, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
```